# How would I change the volume in this script? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

So I have a script used for playing random songs:
http://pastebin.com/G5JNFfY9

I'm not exactly sure how I could alter the volume, could anyone figure it out (audio.volume doesn't work)? I also need to figure out how to change the volume outside of this script since the audio is defined in a function.

Also, I need an example on how to buffer this more efficiently.

Comment: You can use the “format code” button (`{}`) to put the code in your question. Also, please pick one question per question. =)

Comment: Alright, I'll do as instructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `audio.volume` you just have to have a way of retrieving the currently playing audio

```js
var collection=[];// final collection of sounds to play
var loadedIndex=0;// horrible way of forcing a load of audio sounds
var range = document.getElementById('range');
 
// remap audios to a buffered collection
function init(audios) {
  for(var i=0;i<audios.length;i++) {
    var audio = new Audio(audios[i]);
    collection.push(audio);
    audio.volume = range.value/100;
    buffer(audio);
  }
}
 
// did I mention it's a horrible way to buffer?
function buffer(audio) {
  if(audio.readyState==4)return loaded();
  setTimeout(function(){buffer(audio)},100);
}
 
// check if we're leady to dj this
function loaded() {
  loadedIndex++;
  if(collection.length==loadedIndex)playLooped();
}
 
// play and loop after finished
function playLooped() {
  var audioIndex=Math.floor(Math.random() * (collection.length));
  var audio=collection[audioIndex];
  audio.play();
  // you weren't saving off the index when it changes songs
  loadedIndex = audioIndex;
  setTimeout(playLooped,audio.duration*1000);
}

// change volume
function changeVolume(e) {
  var value = Number(e.target.value)
  collection[loadedIndex].volume = value/100;
  e.target.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].nodeValue = value + '%';
}
 
// the songs to be played!
init([
  'http://popsplit.us/assets/music/1.mp3',
  'http://popsplit.us/assets/music/2.mp3'
]);
```

```html
<body>
<label for="range">Volume</label>
<input type="range" oninput="changeVolume(event)" id="range" min="0" max="100" />
<span class="output-volume">50%</span>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I get the chance and give you my results.

Comment: the above snippet runs in the browser, it lets you change the volume

Comment: Alright, I see the changes.

Comment: yeah, I added one thing to save off the index, but other than that, I just wrote the `changeVolume` function

Comment: Well I know that, you've made some changes to your answer since the first time I've seen it

Comment: yeah, just making it a little prettier. I added the label and the current value, but that is just to be fancy.

Comment: Easier for debugging perhaps